# Automation Studio send a lower amount of emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automationstudio, send-email

I have a question, does anyone know why when an email is send with Automation Studio the amount of emails send are lower that expected?

For example, I need to send 20,000 emails, I have a DE with those records but when the emails are sent, the report said that the amount is 17,480 instead of 20,000.

Maybe this is related an incorrect email address?

Comment: Could be duplicates, list detective, unsubscribes and/or suppressions that are lowering your total sent.

Comment: Thanks! We have a lot of subscribers with an status of undeliverable.